# Heroku ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: heroku

I'm getting this error when i try git push heroku master
and when i click to the link i get this message "Method Not Allowed"
What can i do to fix this? The Error start from this line

```
remote:          Downloading heroku-0.1.4.tar.gz (10 kB)
remote:        Processing /tmp/build/80754af9/idna_1593446292537/work
remote:        ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build/80754af9/idna_1593446292537/work'
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to bonney.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/bonney.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/bonney.git'
```

and this is my requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.2.10
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
brotlipy==0.7.0
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.9.2
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.8
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
heroku==0.1.4
idna @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/idna_1593446292537/work
psycopg2 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/psycopg2_1594305108220/work
pycparser==2.20
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2020.1
requests @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/requests_1592841827918/work
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.9
whitenoise==5.1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Follow the below steps:

1. Check your package --> `conda list` (I used conda env)
2. Edit the package in `requirements.txt` match that I've checked
3. ex.psycopg2 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/psycopg2_1594305108220/work
   --> psycopg2==2.8.5
4. Then commit all changes
5. -push to heroku (I used heroku)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue when I make use of anaconda and I want to deploy the project on heroku server
How i solved it
at the root of my project

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
# edited the content of the requirements.txt e.g
From
Jinja2 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jinja2_1624781299557/work
To
Jinja2==3.0.1  
# you can have access to the packages version with command
pip freeze
```

Or simply using the command below, you can replace all the @file with the version number you have in the environment -

```
pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

Once you are through substituting the url to the version number of each package found in the requirement.txt file then proceed with

```
git add .
git commit -m "comment"
heroku login
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your requirements.txt, remove

idna @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/idna_1593446292537/work
psycopg2 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/psycopg2_1594305108220/work
requests @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/requests_1592841827918/work

then add requirements via git add
and commit

then run push to heroku